# validation pass if there's a date or if there's an empty node

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I would like the validation pass if there's a date or if there's an empty node

`<Start_Date>2011-05-31</Start_Date`> should be ok as well as

```
<Start_Date></Start_Date>
```

My xml is  as follows

```
<Start_Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:nil="true"></Start_Date>
```

and my xsd is as follows

```
<xs:element name="Start_Date" nillable="true" type="xs:date" />
```

My validation works properly if the node is not empty,but whenever i try to pass a date is throws exception saying "Start_Date cannot have character or element information[children],because http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance,nil is specified"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the XML which elicited the error was not

```
<Start_Date>2011-05-31</Start_Date>
```

but

```
<Start_Date 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:nill='true'
>2011-05-31</Start_Date>`
```